# Ace editor not showing HTML code in editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace-editor

Ace editor is not showing HTML code in the editor as shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4sRt.png), but JavaScript and CSS are fine. The code I am using is

```
var html = ace.edit("htmlEditor");
var css = ace.edit("cssEditor");
var js = ace.edit("jsEditor");

html.setTheme("ace/theme/xcode");
css.setTheme("ace/theme/xcode");
js.setTheme("ace/theme/xcode");

html.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");
css.session.setMode("ace/mode/css");
js.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your own html code editor instead.

**HTML**

```html
<textarea oninput="run(this.value)"></textarea>
<iframe id="preview" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
function run(code) {
  document.getElementById("preview").contentDocument.body.innerHTML = code;
}
```

This editor is **Live**. Also, if you want a debugger, use this.

**JavaScript**

```js
function debug(code) {
  try {
    new Function(code);
  } catch(e) {
    alert(e)
  }
}
```

when there is no error, it doesn't alert but it's run the result. else, it alerts the error.

Comment: The question was to fix ace, but you provided a non-relative answer.